# Unity Warning Build encountered MonoBehaviour or ScriptableObject without a registered path

Tags: unity-game-engine

While building on Android, my project gives out a lot of the warnings like the following:

```
 Build encountered MonoBehaviour or ScriptableObject without a registered path. Script name "xxxxx" InstanceID 194830
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

I don't know how to go about fixing this issue; an internet search did not prove helpful at all. Can someone help with where to start?